# How to use the construction 'most unfortunately' properly ?

Tags: meaning, usage

Example: 'Most unfortunately, I haven't found anything.' - the adverb is used as an introductory phrase and has the meaning of an empathy and sorrow.  - is it correct?

I know that it can be used like: 'the most unfortunately named places'
'the most unfortunately placed ads'
to describe all the awkwardness of the way something was done.

Can you please explain if the first example of usage is correct?

Comment: Check here: https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22most+unfortunately%22&spell=1&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiR-_GQ5-XMAhVFvRoKHYniAmUQBQgZKAA&biw=360&bih=512&dpr=2

Comment: *Most unfortunately, I haven't found anything* is technically correct, but I think it sounds awkward. "Most unfortunately" is a strong phrase, and if you use it too much it would sound overly dramatic.

Answer (score 1):

All the examples provided are proper uses of the phrase 'most unfortunately'.

> Merriam-Webster: unfortunately
>
> 1. in a regrettable, unlucky, or unsuitable manner

The example in question could easily have been written as: Most regrettably, I haven't found anything.  As you guessed, the introductory phrase is adding empathy and sorrow.

For the examples 'the most unfortunately named places' and 'the most unfortunately placed ads' the phrase 'most unfortunately' is adding a sense of regret and unsuitability.